# Order UITableView cells by calculated distance (Parse)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a problem with the database created on parse. I have a table that shows me how many miles of the various local (once you download the list from DB) the problem is that I would order it for distance upward, but I do not know how to do. The code I used to calculate the distance is this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Ristoranti";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"NomeLocale";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 100;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {

        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshTable:)
                                                 name:@"refreshTable"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)refreshTable:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // Reload the recipes
    [self loadObjects];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    query.limit = 100;

    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *AntDef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"AnteprimaDefault"]];

    if ([AntDef isEqualToString:@"Null"])
    {   
        PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageDefault.png"];
        thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        thumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        thumbnailImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    }

    else
    {   
        PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"Anteprima1"];
        PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
        thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
        thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];
    }



    Lat = [[object objectForKey:@"Latitudine"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    Long = [[object objectForKey:@"Longitudine"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    Latdouble = [Lat doubleValue];
    Longdouble = [Long doubleValue];


    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Latdouble longitude:Longdouble], nil];

    //NSLog(@"LOCATIONS COORDINATE: %@", locations);

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];;
    CLLocation *nearestLoc = nil;
    CLLocationDistance nearestDis = FLT_MAX;

    for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
        CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location];

        for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
            distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
            if (nearestDis > distance) {
                nearestLoc = location;
                nearestDis = distance;
            }
        }

        text12 = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%.1f Km", nearestDis/1000];
    }

...
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Order it before configuring the `UITableViewCells`. Manage your data source (array) before loading the data to the `UITableView`

Comment: I am using PFQueryTableViewController, so I should calculate the distance when taking the query? Or am I wrong? However, the route calculation is performed in "local"on server is not present anything

Comment: I don't use `Parse.com`, so either you can ask from an "already" sorted array source, or once you get your data, (and may add a "closest field" to it) you sort it , and then you do `[yourTableView reloadData]`

Comment: So should I create an array with all distances and reorder it later? And how should I do? you may kindly give me an example? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your response data from `Parse.com` is a `NSArray`.

I'd suggest:

- Do the request.
- Sort the `NSArray`
- Reload Data.

Sorting the array could be done like this using the block: `sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b)`

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [initialDataArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
   //Here do the method to compare if `a` is closer or `b` is closer
   YourParseObject *aObject = (YourParseObject *)a;
   YourParseObject *bObject = (YourParseObject *)b;
   //Get Latitude & Longitude from a and b.
   //return NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedDescending according to which one of a or b is the closest, using your previous method I suppose to be working.

}];
```

So `sortedArray` will look like this:

```
{
 YourParseObject the closest one
 YourParseObject the second closest one
 //...
 YourParseObject the farthest one.
}
```

Once it's done:

```
[yourTableView reloadData]
```

Comment: I did not understand where and how to implement it, I edited the code, now entered the complete code that I am using

Comment: This answer is correct, but using the PFQueryTableViewController I believe it should be placed in the objectsDidLoad: method. You can see the class reference here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/loadObjects  You should sort the objects property of your view controller. I believe that should occur before the objects are loaded into the table

Comment: you could have an example with the data that I have to understand? I can not make it work

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue today and found out that Parse.com has already implemented this solution:

If you're using Parse's `PFQueryTableViewController.h`, you'd want to add this into your `queryForTable` method:

> - (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];    
        [query whereKey:@"yourClassPFLocationField" nearGeoPoint:yourLocation];
    return query;
}
```

The same applies if you're not using the `PFQueryTable`, just use that sorting method when loading the query.

Everything is on the `PFQuery` documentation :D